# HMAC sha256 returning different values in c# than python

Tags: c#, python, sha256

I need to port some python code into c# and I'm having some trouble with this line:

> Python

```
hmac.new(key, message,digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
```

> C#

```
HMACSHA256 hm = new HMACSHA256(key);
byte[] result = hm.ComputeHash(enc.GetBytes(message));
```

Why am I getting a different result in C# when key and message are the same (checked byte-by-byte) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get different hashes for the same message if you use different encodings when converting the message into a byte array. It is not clear which encoding you are using, but the point is that they should match.

For example:

```
hmac.new("mykey", "mymessage",digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
```

> gTM3eMvH4WsjwCGzp4gZNV5a62dEcWw/gjTMPngjJpQ=

In C# you get different results depending on your 'enc' variable.

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("ASCII");
```

> gTM3eMvH4WsjwCGzp4gZNV5a62dEcWw/gjTMPngjJpQ=

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("Unicode");
```

> 2wqHPyE5oiI3ukxOaKo9ao6AN8fcwjgdDInBHTXTwGQ=

Comment: Thanks. I still can't figure out which encoding the python function uses. I have tried chardet and it detects it as windows-1251 but it's not that one. I have tried UTF 7,8,16,32 and Unicode but it doesn't seem to be one of those.